# How to center vertically an image using flex box?

Tags: html, css, ionic2, flexbox

I'm trying to center vertically  an image using flex box.

This is my code:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div class="logo-part">
          <img id="logo" src="assets/logo/logo.png" alt="img-logo">
          <ion-title>Service at your fingertips!</ion-title>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

CSS:

```
ion-content ion-grid {
  height: 100%;
}
ion-content ion-row{
  height: 50%;
}
div.logo-part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
img{
width:25%;
text-align:center;
}
```

The image is not positioning in the cente vertically!

Any help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of `flex-direction: column`, when you use this, `align-items` starts aligning horizontally not vertically, to align vertically you will need to set `justify-content: center`

> Just to explain this behavior: this is because justify-content aligns according to the main direction and align-items according to the intersection. So, when you change flex-direction from row (horizontal) to column (vertical), justify-content aligns vertically and align-items horizontally.
>   - [Rodrigo Ferreira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8371135/rodrigo-ferreira)

Comment: Just to explain this behavior: this is because justify-content aligns according to the main direction and align-items according to the intersection. So, when you change flex-direction from row (horizontal) to column (vertical), justify-content aligns vertically and align-items horizontally.

Comment: Thank you, english is not my native language, I can't explain so well as you